# FCM push notification doesn't arrive if json contains an empty string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have integrate fcm in my android app and everything is working perfectly if json contains all the values perfectly. The problem is started when it contains a key with empty value. Yes if json has a key that contains an empty value than push notification doesn't arrive. Any solution is there?

Here is my json :

```
{ "data": { "message": "", "url": "www.google.com" } }
```

Here message contains an empty value at that time notification doesn't arrive.

Comment: Post your notification receiver code to check what's the actual issue

Comment: does it not arrive, or does your app not handle it?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options you have data message or notification message?

Comment: Empty string is valid data so should not affect the message being received. I also think you should check the handling of the incoming message when the message is an empty string.